# how to show loading image indicator inside uitable?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, three20

i'm new using Trhee20 in Xcode and i'm building an APP that needs to send a post request to a page to register a new user using the following code:

```
TTURLRequest *request = [TTURLRequest requestWithURL:page delegate:self];
request.httpMethod = @"POST";
request.cachePolicy = TTURLRequestCachePolicyNoCache; 

request.response = [[[TTURLJSONResponse alloc] init] autorelease];

[request.parameters addObject:nombre forKey:@"username"];
[request.parameters addObject:email forKey:@"email"];
[request.parameters addObject:pass1 forKey:@"pass"];
[request.parameters addObject:pass2 forKey:@"cpass"];
```

I know that i need to use:`[request sendSynchronously];`to send the data but i don't know how to save the data that i'll retrieve from the server into a variable because this method only gives me a true or false.

The second thing i would like to know is how to set an image loading activity indicator into a uitable to block this while the request is being send to the server and quit that image once it has finished.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Answer #1: You set up a [TTURLRequestDelegate](http://api.three20.info/protocol_t_t_u_r_l_request_delegate-p.php) and define the methods of what you want to happen for each callback.

Answer #2: This isn't Three20 specific, you should just be able to add the loading image when you make the request, and then remove it once you get one of the above mentioned delegate methods called.

On a side note: make sure that if you're actually doing something synchronously that you do not do it on the UI thread as it will make your app hang.

Comment: For dealing with graphic issues (caching) of the loading image and/or *UIActivityIndicatorView* inside the *UITableViewCell*, consider using the **tag** property of the cell. If the **tag** is set to some value (preferably declared in an typedef) show the graphic in the cell.